# how to make a chrome extension to copy selection to clipboard

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

I wanna make a extension to copy selection to clipboasd by clicking the ContextMenu.
In chrome,many people use a flash solusion.But how can use flash in ContextMenus.It seems impossible.Who can tell me a solusion?

What I did

```
var a = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title":copy,"context":["selection"],"onclick":copy});
function copy(info,tab){
document.execCommand('selectAll'); //just for example
document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

I have add clipboardWrite permisson to manifest.json.But it seems doesn't work.
"permission":["contextMenus","clipboardWrite"]

Comment: [This][1] should help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436102/copy-to-clipboard-in-chrome-extension

Comment: The Experimental Clipboard API has been removed and chrome doesn't support document.execCommand("Copy") and how can I use a flash in ContextMenus.

Comment: May be the experimental API is no longer experimental?  http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions

Answer (score 5):

Add this permission into your manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [ "clipboardWrite" ]
```

And to copy to clipboard:

```
document.execCommand('copy', false, null);
```

Comment: I have done that.But it dosn't work ,either.It seems that"document.execCommand('copy')" is also right.

Comment: Then i would suggest to look at the code of Google Url Shortner chrome extension.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iblijlcdoidgdpfknkckljiocdbnlagk

Once you install it in chrome and if you use linux, then goto ~/.config/google-chrome/iblijlcdoidgdpfknkckljiocdbnlagk/

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps.
A recent addition to manifest's permissions are `clipboardRead` and `clipboardWrite`.
Theese let your extension to use the method `document.execCommand('copy')`, for example.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions

Comment: What does it mean by"This permission is required for hosted apps"?

Comment: In Google Chrome extension API documentation, I understand that means that, if you are coding a hosted APP, and need access to clipboard, you will need this permission.  Otherwise, it wouldn't be needed, I don't know in which cases.  A hosted App is a regular web pages, with an "installable" manifest that allows extra permissions, like an extension, bringing to pages the power of extensions.