# Write text to Clipboard

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

I want to write some text variable into clipboard via Chrome Extension, it will be happened when user presses a short-key. I've done all parts except writing to clipboard.

I've searched entire StackOverflow using these keywords:
"[google-chrome-extension] Clipboard"

So I want to say, I've seen all related to:

- Add `clipboardRead` and `clipboardWrite` permission (already done)
- Add text into a `<textarea>`, call
  `document.execCommand('Copy');`
  or
  `document.execCommand("Copy", false, null);`

Even I tried my extension on StackOverflow's `textarea` and I inserted my text into wmd-input part of StackOverflow `textarea`, then selected it, then called copy. Nothing, nothing, nothing...

Everything tried. Please advise... What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following code, it writes text to clipboard

As an example i wrote `Sample` to clipboard

### Output

[image]

#### ***manifest.json***

manifest file is key for all chrome extensions, ensured it is with all permissions

```
 {
  "name": "Copy to ClipBoard Demo",
  "description" : "This is used for demonstrating Copy to Clip Board Functionality",
  "version": "1",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions":["clipboardWrite"],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

#### ***popup.html***

A trivial Browser action HTML File, with input box and button

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="text" placeHolder="Enter Text To Copy"></input>
        <button id="copy">Copy</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

#### ***popup.js***

It copies content in `<input>` to clipboard

```
function copy() {

    //Get Input Element
    var copyDiv = document.getElementById('text');

    //Give the text element focus
    copyDiv.focus();

    //Select all content
    document.execCommand('SelectAll');

    //Copy Content
    document.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
}

//Add Event Listeners to Button Click
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById("copy").onclick = copy;
});
```

#### OR

```
function copy(){

    //Get Input Element
    document.getElementById("text").select();

    //Copy Content
    document.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
}

//Add Event Listeners to Button Click
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById("copy").onclick = copy;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sudarshan, it worked on Popup, but I already have a variable (output) from content script which I want to copy that text to clipbaord, how I should do that?

Comment: @DavidBrisker: You mean to say, you have content to be copied is in content scripts variable?

Comment: I copied your work in background js and it worked well. But in background page I cannot receive keyboard event. I want copying happen when user presses a keyboard shortcut

Comment: @DavidBrisker: If you can edit your question with code which is not working, it can help me better to understand problem, can you please put your relevant code by editing your question? I can pick it up from there

Comment: Code is a little complicated, but assume this: I want to have a key event listener which when user clicked for example Alt + 9, copy a variable data (which I see via alert or console.log) to clipboard. Hooking keyboard event only achievable in content script not background script (as far as I know) and copying text to clipboard achievable only via background script (as far as I know), how can I handle it?

Comment: `Hooking keyboard event only achievable in content script not background script (as far as I know)` content script key board listeners are hooked in content script and background script keyboard listeners are hooked in background script;`copying text to clipboard achievable only via background script (as far as I know),` it is also possible in content script, have you tried `document.execCommand("Copy", false, null);` in your content script?

Comment: Thats sudarshan, using sendmessage, sent message from content to background and background copied it to clipboard. :) Thanks

Comment: Ok, you can also try this approach `var texttobecopied = $('#someid').val(str).select();
    document.execCommand('copy');` to copy from content script(s), but i did not test it :)..Edited by answer with another approach

Answer (score 11):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/12693636

```
function directCopy(str){
    //based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/12693636
        document.oncopy = function(event) {
    event.clipboardData.setData("Text", str);
    event.preventDefault();
        };
    document.execCommand("Copy");
        document.oncopy = undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usage example:

copyStringToClipboard("abc123");

```
    function copyStringToClipboard (str) {
      // Create new element
      var el = document.createElement('textarea');
      // Set value (string to be copied)
      el.value = str;
      // Set non-editable to avoid focus and move outside of view
      el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
      el.style = {position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px'};
      document.body.appendChild(el);
      // Select text inside element
      el.select();
      // Copy text to clipboard
      document.execCommand('copy');
      // Remove temporary element
      document.body.removeChild(el);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Suonds like you're trying to copy from a content script. Building off [joelpt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313177/joelpt) and [Jeff Gran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/835766/jeff-gran)'s answers from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436102/copy-to-clipboard-in-chrome-extension), here's how to copy any piece of text from a content script:

> ```
> "permissions": [
>     "clipboardWrite",...
> ```

In your main.js or any background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
  var copyFrom = document.createElement("textarea");
  copyFrom.textContent = request.text;
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.appendChild(copyFrom);
  copyFrom.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  body.removeChild(copyFrom);
})
```

From your content script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({text:textToCopy});
```