# How to get Clipboard data in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

I'm having a hard time finding any recent info on how to add a listener for "Ctrl+C", fetching clipboard data, and then writing back to clipboard all in a Chrome Extension. All of the old code that i found was for the older versions that are now deprecated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Basically you can manipulate clipboard using `document.execCommand('paste|copy|cut')`.

- You'll need to specify `"clipboardWrite"` and/or `"clipboardRead"` [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) in manifest.

  > "clipboardRead" Required if the extension or app uses document.execCommand('paste').
  >
  > "clipboardWrite"    Indicates the extension or app uses document.execCommand('copy') or document.execCommand('cut'). This permission is required for hosted apps; it's recommended for extensions and packaged apps.
- Create `<input>` element (or `<textarea>`)
- Put focus to it
- Call `document.execCommand('paste')`
- Grab you string from `<input>` `value` attribute.

This worked for me to copy data to clipboard.

Comment: Can I use 'paste' to pull data from the clipboard?

Comment: Yes, it should work. I've updated answer. Otherwise I don't see why chrome will need `clipboardWrite` permission.

Comment: To paste the clipboard content, you need the permission to read the clipboard, not write.. I updated the answer. To make il clear: If you want to copy to the clipboard, you need the write permissions

Comment: Added both examples

Answer (score 19):

In order to read Clipboard text in a chrome extension, you have to:

- request "clipboardRead" permission in your manifest
- create a background script, since only the background script can access the clipboard
- create an element in your background page to accept the clipboard paste action. If you make this a textarea, you will get plain-text, if you make it a div with contentEditable=true, you will get Formatted HTML
- if you want to pass the clipboard data back to an in page script, you'll need to use the message-passing API

To see an example of this all working, see my BBCodePaste extension:

https://github.com/jeske/BBCodePaste

Here is one example of how to read the clipboard text in the background page:

```
bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();        // get the background page
bg.document.body.innerHTML= "";                   // clear the background page

// add a DIV, contentEditable=true, to accept the paste action
var helperdiv = bg.document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(helperdiv);
helperdiv.contentEditable = true;

// focus the helper div's content
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(helperdiv);
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
helperdiv.focus();    

// trigger the paste action
bg.document.execCommand("Paste");

// read the clipboard contents from the helperdiv
var clipboardContents = helperdiv.innerHTML;
```

Comment: In background.js you don't need to get and use the variable bg, just use document.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a very simple solution. All it requires is for your permissions to include `"clipboardRead"` and `"clipboardWrite"`. The `copyTextToClipboard` function is taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18455088/4204557

```
var t = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(t);
t.focus();
document.execCommand("paste");
var clipboardText = t.value; //this is your clipboard data
copyTextToClipboard("Hi" + clipboardText); //prepends "Hi" to the clipboard text
document.body.removeChild(t);
```

Note that `document.execCommand("paste")` is disabled in Chrome, and will only work in a Chrome extension, not in a web page.

Answer (score 4):

Best workable examples I found are [here](https://barrysimpson.net/posts/copy-paste-chrome-ext)
below example worked for me, sharing here so that someone can get help

```
function getClipboard() {
    var result = null;
    var textarea = document.getElementById('ta');
    textarea.value = '';
    textarea.select();

    if (document.execCommand('paste')) {
        result = textarea.value;
    } else {
        console.log('failed to get clipboard content');
    }

    textarea.value = '';
    return result;
}
```