# Read\write clipboard data in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

I'm writing extension for Google Chrome. I'm trying to read\write data from clipboard using this method:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
     code: "document.addEventListener('copy', function(e){ var data=e.clipboardData.getData('text'); alert(data);});"   
  })
```

But, it didn't work. If I correctly understood this [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#the-copy-action), above method should work. So, what could be the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Clipboard data in Chrome Extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702446/how-to-get-clipboard-data-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: Cᴀʟʟᴏᴅᴀᴄɪᴛʏ, i'm interested exactly in clipboardData.getData method

Comment: `event.clipboardData.getData()` returns a zero length string from `copy` and `cut` events.  It does return valid data from `paste` events.

Comment: I think Makyen is on to something. See [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#dfn-allowed-to-read-from-clipboard) on when you can read the clipboard. Do you have the `"clipboardRead"` permission? Even then, it may only work within the extension context and not the content script.