# How do I prompt user for clipboard read permission in the popup of the chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, html5-clipboard-api

I am building out my first Google Chrome Extension and want to create something that can read and write to the system clipboard.
I am currently putting all the js in a script imported by the popup.html for the extension.

I also have permissions declared in the `manifest.json` for `clipboard-read` and `clipboard-write`.

I was able to write data into the clipboard, but I am unable to read from it.

I have a `button` on the `popup.html` that has an `id` and in the js I am getting element by id and adding a eventlistener for click that fires a function called paste which in turn invokes `navigator.clipboard.readText()`. From my understanding, that is supposed to prompt for permission, but it is not doing anything.

Do you know if it's okay to invoke `readText` from the `popup.html`?
If so, how would get the prompt to show up? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most likely a bug in Chrome as I remember seeing it on https://crbug.com. You'll have to use the classic approach - look up "document.execCommand paste". Note, the permission names are clipboardRead and clipboardWrite.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for the suggestion, will test out the document.execCommand. I noticed some docs say the permission for clipboard read is clipboard-read and others say clipboardRead. Strange.

Comment: Extension permissions were always camelCase. Anything else is a mistake.

Comment: Used the document.execCommand and it worked! Thanks @wOxxOm

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702446/how-to-get-clipboard-data-in-chrome-extension/43375402

Answer (score -2):

If you include JQuery as a background script you can use this (I use this all the time in my chrome extensions) to move text to the clipboard and then if you have a past method you can do that in the settimeout...

```
function copyUsingJquery(element_id) {
            $(element_id).attr("contenteditable", true)
              .select()
              .on("focus", function () {
                  document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null)
              })
              .focus();
            document.execCommand("Copy");
            $(element_id).removeAttr("contenteditable");

            setTimeout(function () {
                //deslect text on page after a few seconds
                //$(element_id).trigger("blur");
                window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            }, 5000);

        }
```

and then call the above function with the following where some_html is your element (could be a div/must be visible or positioned to not be visible...

```
copyUsingJquery("#some_html");
```

Hope this helps.