# Javascript access clipboard without event on http/local file

Tags: javascript, dom-events, clipboard

I have a website which will only be accessed via browsers I have full control of and I want to access the clipboard on load. I can't use the Clipboard API, since the website is served locally or over http (not https). I also can't use `e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')`, since I don't have an event to call it on. Any ideas on how to access the Clipboard?

Comment: Clipboard API should work with `localhost` as is, otherwise you can check this flag `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`. Not sure about Firefox.

Comment: @Walk the flag sadly doesn't work for local websites

Comment: I see, perhaps you can create a small browser extension. These can access clipboard, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702446/how-to-get-clipboard-data-in-chrome-extension/43375402

Comment: Did you try using the Clipboard API? Its not dependent on the protocol

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava the api can only be used in a "Secure context", aka over https

Comment: @Teiem — So use HTTPS. Get a self-signed cert for your internal services.