# Can i access all copied content via javascript from any tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, copy-paste

I am working on google chrome extension and working on a way around for accessing copied content (CTRL + C), but found out Clipboard which has a limited scope of availability only. Is there any possible ways to access via javascript.

Comment: You can do it in the background script or browser_action script, see [How to get Clipboard data in Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22702446)

Comment: Thanks man it did work