# Failed to read clipboard contents DOMException

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was developing an extension for chrome which copies a range of values from a column in a spreadsheet and when i press Ctrl+m key its pastes(pops) values one by one. Script worked when i put it in an HTML page, however if load the the extension in chrome in developer mode and test it , it throws the error "Failed to read clipboard contents: [object DOMException]" Here is code snippet and screenshot

```js
navigator.clipboard.readText()
  .then(text => {
    values = text.split(/[\s,]+/);
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

      if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'm') {
        var shiftedVal = values.shift();
        if (shiftedVal != null) {
          document.activeElement.value = shiftedVal;
        } else {
          alert("No more values. Que is Empty");
        }
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err);
  });
```

Screen Shot of Error
[image]

Comment: It's a bug. Use the old method: [How to get Clipboard data in Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53731721)