# Copying to Clipboard in a content Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Can someone explain how I can write to clipboard please? I've seen a lot of ways but I cant seem to understand how. Currently using manifest v3 and no background.js script.

`popup.js (action: download)` -> `contentscript.js (see below)`

```
function listener(info) {

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

            if (!request.action) return sendResponse({
                err: 'Error: No Request Action'
            });

            switch (request.action) {
                case "copy":

                    var textCopy = info.links.join(', ').replace(/"/g, '') // Text to Copy (String)

                    navigator.clipboard.writeText(textCopy).then(() => {
                        sendResponse('success')
                    }, () => {
                        sendResponse('failed')
                    });

                    break;

                // Other Requests
               
            }

        }
    );
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your code? Which API do you use to send the message? Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: it doesnt copy to clipboard, using `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` to send messages to the content script, would that effect the content scripts ability to copy to clipboard?

Comment: The clipboard is just one per the entire system so you can write to it in your popup.js.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @cactus12 for the help here's the code that worked for me!

```
var textCopy = '' // Text to Copy
var copyFrom = document.createElement("textarea");

copyFrom.textContent = `${textCopy}`;
document.body.appendChild(copyFrom);

copyFrom.select();
document.execCommand(`copy`);

copyFrom.blur();
document.body.removeChild(copyFrom);
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in manifest v2, this method works.

---

First you need to add the permission `clipboardWrite` to your manifest:

```
...
"permissions": ["clipboardWrite", ... ],
...
```

Then do something like what was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18455088

The idea is to create a temporary text area to put the text in which then allows you to select all the text inside with `.select()` and then copy it with `document.execCommand('copy')`.

Comment: just did some research and according to w3schools `'execCommand()'` is depreciated

Comment: It's deprecated but it doesn't matter.

Comment: oh cheers, working now! I'll post the code for anyone interested